# Error handling codeigniter and phpactiverecord

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling, phpactiverecord

I'm new to CodeIgniter and PhpActiverecord and I'm wondering how to best propagate errors from the Model to the Controller when using CI and phpactiverecord. As a simple example consider this:

```
class Book extends ActiveRecord\Model {

  static $validates_presence_of = array(
    array('title')
  );

  public static function new_book($title){
    $new_record = Book::create(array(
      'title' => $title
    ));

    if($new_record->is_invalid())
      //propagate error with $new_record->errors->full_messages()
    else
      return $new_record;
  }

}
```

Should I have a variable in my controller that checks if errors has been set or should I just return `$new_record` whatever happens and do the `is_invalid()` check in the controller? I would like to do most of the work in the model (to follow the "fat model skinny controller" principle) but I can't really see a "nice" way of propagating the errors to the controller and on to the view.

Comment: Why aren't you using CodeIgniter's ActiveRecord implementation?

Comment: I followed screencasts on http://heybigname.com/category/screencasts/new-codeigniter-website-series/ that uses phpactiverecord.

Answer (score 2):

Why not add an error reporting method to the model

```
class Book extends ActiveRecord\Model {

  private $errors = array();

  public function get_errors() {
    return $this->errors;
  }

  static $validates_presence_of = array(
    array('title')
  );

  public static function new_book($title){
    $new_record = Book::create(array(
      'title' => $title
    ));

    if($new_record->is_invalid())
      //propagate error with $new_record->errors->full_messages()
      $this->errors[] = $new_record->errors->full_messages()
    else
      return $new_record;
  }

}
```

In the controller, test if a false or NULL value is returned. If so you can call the get_errors() method, do any additional formatting if you choose to, and pass the array to the view.